# Istio default SSL certificate configuration

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress, istio, istio-gateway

The request flow:

Application gateway--> Azure APIM--> APIM Backend (istio)

Goal:

Application gateway--> Azure APIM--> APIM Backend (istio-HTTPS) --> istio Gateway(HTTPS)

We have already configured the same setup in nginx ingress controller instaed of istio. It is working fine with https. Below are the configurations done in the nginx deployment.

```
containers:
      - args
        - --default-ssl-certificate=namespace/tls-secret
```

How we can achieve the same in istio implementation?

Followed steps:

Created secrets in istio-system with crt and key and configured in Gateway. Still getting 500 error

Comment: Are the requests reaching application container?  500 error you are getting from application pod?

Comment: It is not reaching pod. In gateway level itself https handshake is not happening

Comment: In which namespace the secret is created also can share istiod and ingress gateway logs